# Spring Cloud stream app failing due to kafka service access at build

Tags: maven, openshift, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to build my first spring cloud stream app. On eclipse it works fine but when i use
`mvn clean package`
I get below error :

```
        bootstrap.servers = [kafka-svc.msgbus:9093]
        client.dns.lookup = default
        client.id =
        connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
        default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retries = 2147483647
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        security.providers = null
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS

2021-08-17 12:42:16.199  WARN 788572 --- [           main] org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils     : Couldn't resolve server kafka-svc.msgbus:9093 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for kafka-svc.msgbus
2021-08-17 12:42:16.201 ERROR 788572 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService  : Failed to create producer binding; retrying in 30 seconds

org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:479) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.Admin.create(Admin.java:71) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient.create(AdminClient.java:49) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.createAdminClient(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:259) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:160) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.KStreamBinder.doBindProducer(KStreamBinder.java:124) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.KStreamBinder.doBindProducer(KStreamBinder.java:53) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:152) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.doBindProducer(BindingService.java:313) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:282) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:291) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.createAndBindOutputs(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:136) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:58) [spring-cloud-stream-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
```

**Issue**:
Now the DNS kafka-svc.msgbus:9093 is endpoint of a service deployed on openshift (not publically exposed) and accessible by namespaces. Build is happening outside any namespace. Is there a  way to disable this feature in maven ?

My application.properties:

```
server.port = 8089
debug=true
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure=ERROR



##Channel details for process based implementation
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.autonomousProcessor-input-channel.destination = MANAGEMENT
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.autonomousProcessor-output-channel.destination = OUTPUT

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.autonomousProcessor-output-channel.producer.value-serde=io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde


spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
#spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers = localhost:9092
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers = kafka-svc.msgbus:9093
```

Comment: This certainly looks like a networking issue. The broker URI - `kafka-svc.msgbus:9093` is not resolving for some reason. You need to triage that. From a Spring Cloud Stream perspective, your configuration looks good.

Comment: So the issue as mentioned is that this dns is a service url which can be resolved once its inside network of openshift

Comment: Since this is a build-time issue, are your tests running against the real broker? If so, consider using the embedded kafka broker provided by spring-kafka-test or TestContainers.

Comment: Ok, For the time being i saw in my code on importing spring boot starter kit. i was getting the Context Load and it was trying to start stream at build up. I commented contextLoad and worked for now. But I feel your suggetsion of embedded kafka broker should be more efficient. Could you share some Doc links and reference for same, I would study and try it @GaryRussell

Comment: There’s a sample here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/main/testing-samples/test-embedded-kafka - it uses Junit4. See the docs for using it with Junit5  https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#embedded-kafka-junit5